# qsort on a std::vector<float*> _data

Tags: c++

I need help on a sort program for `std::vector<float*> _data`.
The sort criteria can be selected on index i1, i2, i3... of the _data in a ascend manner. The i1 is a 
 `float *i1_data = _data[i1];`

How do I accomplish it?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: Here is an attempt to decode your question. You have a series of N float arrays which you are calling `i1_data` through to `iN_data` and referencing using `float *` pointers. Let's assume they're all the same length, so this is actually a matrix. For some reason you have chosen to store an integer index in `i1_data`, and you want to sort all the other arrays according to the order given in `i1_data`. Am I close? (By the way, it would be helpful if you specified the question more carefully to begin with, to avoid this guesswork.)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a comparison functor

```
struct float_cmp{
    bool operator()(float *f1, float *f2){
        return (*f1) < (*f2);
    }
}

std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), float_cmp);
```

Comment: This will not work, when I do sort on i1_data, the other i2_data, i3_data, and iN_data have to be swapped according to the index in i1_data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do then.  Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either want a boost multiindex, or a single `vector` of a `struct` that has all your data members in it, instead of multiple vectors with a single data type each.